# GIT. Как насильно скопировать изменения из одной ветки в другую

Tags: git, github

Стою на ветке `module2` и нужно перетащить в неё изменения из ветки `module1`

Команда `git cherry-pick module1` приводит к конфликтам, которые я не могу понять как разрешить. Ещё при этом почему-то теряются файлы, которые есть в веткe `module1`.

Можно ли как-то насильно перетащить изменения из одной ветки в другую, что-то типа такого
`git cherry-pick module1 --FORCE`?
Сейчас единственный выход вижу в том чтобы встать на ветку `module1` руками скопировать все директории с файлами в *промежуточную папку*.
Потом вернутся в ветку `module2` и руками перетащить все файлы из *промежуточной папки* в папку проекта.

Короче я сделал кучу работы в ветке module1. А потом выяснилось что работу нужно было вести в ветке module2. Я создал чистую ветку module2 и мне просто нужно перетащить в неё всю сделанную работу в ветке module1.

Comment: Не совсем ясно что вам нужно. Если вы сделаете то, что вы описали как вариант "вручную", то вы просто ветку `module2` сделаете равной ветке `module1` по содержимому, но со своей историей. Этим вы затрете все изменения, которые были сделаны в `module2`, но которых нет в `module1`. Это действительно то, что вам нужно? Может вы хотите, чтоб у вас сохранились изменения из `module2`, но плюс к ним пришли изменения сделанные в `module1`? Если так то вам нужно просто сделать merge ветки `module1` в `module2`.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Сейчас изменю описание вопроса. Короче я сделал кучу работы в ветке module1. А потом выяснилось что работу нужно было вести в ветке module2. Я создал чистую ветку module2 и мне просто нужно перетащить в неё всю сделанную работу в ветке module1.

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно просто переименовать ветку. `git branch -m <oldname> <newname>`. Если ветка уже создана, то тогда просто переставляете ее, чтоб указывала куда вам нужно (на module1): `git branch -f module2 module1`

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA к сожалению нельзя. Нужно чтобы старая ветка (module1) тоже осталась.

Comment: Только, ради бога, сделайте резервную копию репозитория перед тем, как выполнять команды.

Comment: Создаёте ветку `module3` там же где `module1`. В ветке `module1` переносите указатель назад `reset --hard`. Потом новую ветку `module3` переносите на место `module1` с помощью `rebase`. Так не пробовали?

Comment: @AlexGlebe если честно я даже не совсем понял, что вы предлагаете :)
Мне тут знакомый посоветовал на будущее, просто вторую ветку ```module2``` отпочковывать не от ```master```, а от ```module1```, тогда изменения из ```module1``` автоматически будут в ```module2```, что в принципе в моём случае тоже подходит.

Comment: Я в таких случаях делаю ещё один клон репозитория и переписываю файлы из клона в клон. После этого (`add`, `commit`) два бранча становятся полностью одинаковыми. Но они не знают что они родственники. Родство можно закрепить мержем, в котором проблем не будет, так как бранчи одинаковы по составу. Это совет бедного человека, которому трудно разобраться в хитросплетениях гита.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, быстрее будет сделать руками.

1 Встал на ветку `module1`

2 Зашёл в директорию проекта и скопировал от туда целиком папку `src`.

3 Вернулся обратно на ветку `module2`

4 Удалил папку `src` и вместо неё вставил папку `src` c нужными изменениями из ветки `module1`.

5 Закоммитил изменения.

Единственный минус такого подхода, что история добавления фич осталось вся в ветке `module1`. А в ветке `module2` сейчас один коммит в котором собрана куча изменений.

Answer (score 0):

*m1 == ветка module1 , m2 == ветка module2 , m3 == ветка module3 , old == коммиты старые , new == коммит новый*

```
  old1 -- new : m1
   
  old2 : m2
```

Сначала создаём ветку `module3` на месте нового кода.

```
git checkout master1
git branch master3

  old1 -- new : m1 , m3
   
  old2 : m2
```

Потом переносим указатель `module1` назад.

```
git checkout master1
git reset --hard old1

  old1 : m1 -- new : m3
   
  old2 : m2
```

Дальше уже перенос ветки `module3` на другую `module2`.

```
git checkout module3
git rebase module2

  old1 : m1
   
  old2 : m2 -- new : m3
```

Подтягиваем ветку `module2` вперёд к новому модулю `module3`.

```
git checkout module2
git pull module3

  old1 : m1
   
  old2 -- new : m2 , m3
```

Сложность переноса зависит сильной разницы веток `module1` и `module2`. И команда `rebase --hard` может быть запрещена, если ваша ветка удалённая на сервере.

Comment: Спасибо что потратили своё время, я потом попробую расшифровать, то что вы написали.
Честно говоря понятнее не стало, я пока только учусь. В конце февраля этого года записался на курсы.
Поэтому пока такой синтаксис мне не совсем понятен.
Двоеточия, запятые, это всё в командной строке нужно писать ( old1 -- new : m1 , m3)?

Comment: ` old1 -- new : m1 , m3
   
  old2 : m2`
Это похоже не команда, а схема веток в git.

Comment: Не тяжко, чет всё равно не соображу